# Как установить timezone сервера для докер контейнера?

Tags: linux, docker, консоль, timezone

/etc/timezone - в файле таймзона указана верно, в докер контейнере тайм зона вообще другая.

Есть команда для запуска контейнера. 
docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ololo -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -d -p 5432:5432 -v /opt/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata postgres

Что и куда в нее нужно добавить, чтоб запустить докер контейнер с той же тайм зоной, которая указана для сервера?

Comment: Держи ссылку, там есть подробные ответы, в том числе и я отвечал.
[Using docker-compose to set containers timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172652/using-docker-compose-to-set-containers-timezones/54532141#54532141)

Comment: Вот здесь посмотри развернутое описание:
[Using docker-compose to set timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172652/using-docker-compose-to-set-containers-timezones/54532141#54532141)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно ещё одну переменную окружения передать (с помощью опции `-e`) — `TZ`. сравните:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti debian date
Tue Nov 19 15:56:40 UTC 2019
$ docker run --rm -ti -e TZ=Europe/Moscow debian date
Tue Nov 19 18:56:40 MSK 2019
```

Comment: А контейнеры разве не берут время из хоста? Вроде "своё" время только железным виртуалкам доступно.

Comment: @donRumata, да, именно оттуда и берут. но время и часовой пояс — это разные сущности.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin подскажите пожалуйста как правильно ее в строке передать) docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e TZ=Europe/Moscow pg-docker date -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ololo -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -d -p 5432:5432 -v /opt/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata postgres ?

Comment: @АлисаЛамехова, две переменных вы же уже передаёте: `-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ololo` и `-e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata`. добавьте рядом и третью.

Answer (score 1):

Укажите такую же таймзону принудительно одним из способов:

- docker run -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
- docker run -e TZ=Asia/Jakarta